# PLSQL - Generating Server List By Group

Tags: oracle, plsql

My table looks like

```
group1,serverA
group1,serverB
group2,serverA
group3,serverC
```

I want to generate output showing in PLSQL

```
group1
serverA
serverB

group2
serverA

group3
serverC
```

I know I have done this before , but late this Friday evening , I cant think for the life of me how to get it done.

I will continue to dig , but any help appreciated!

Comment: Does your table have two columns, one with the group the second with the server; or a single column with a CSV string? Are you trying to get a result set with that output - in 7 rows, or in 9, with blank rows, and how will the consumer know how to order them? Or are you really just trying to print them out from PL/SQL, e.g. with `dbms_output`?

Comment: Hi Alex , thanks for your comment. I should have been a little clearer perhaps. I had 2 columns , 1st with group , 2nd with server.  Output was PLSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a slow lunch-hour:

```
DECLARE 
  strLast_grp   VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  -- Test statements here
  FOR aRow IN (WITH cteCsv_data AS (SELECT 'group1,serverA' AS CSV FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                                    SELECT 'group1,serverB' AS CSV FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                                    SELECT 'group2,serverA' AS CSV FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                                    SELECT 'group3,serverC' AS CSV FROM DUAL),
                    cteGrp_srv AS  (SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(c.CSV, '(.*),.*', '\1')) AS GRP,
                                           TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(c.CSV, '.*,(.*)', '\1')) AS SRV
                                      FROM cteCsv_data c)
               SELECT gs.GRP, gs.SRV
                 FROM cteGrp_srv gs
                 ORDER BY gs.GRP, gs.SRV)
  LOOP
    IF strLast_grp IS NULL OR strLast_grp <> aRow.GRP THEN
      strLast_grp := aRow.GRP;

      IF strLast_grp IS NOT NULL THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' ');
      END IF;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(aRow.GRP);
    END IF;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(aRow.SRV);
  END LOOP;  -- aRow
END;
```

Comment: Well Bob it was a productive one :) Many thanks for your detail. I had expected some pointers and perhaps someone telling me to Google a bit harder , but alas the World still has some heroes left. Thanks again and have a great day.